# I am trying to change the style of li tags in just ol tags but getting error message- items[i].document is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

```
let items = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let it = items[i].document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(let j = 0; j < it.length;j++){
        it[j].setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;")
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the `style` of `li` tags in just `ol` tags but getting an error message:

> items[i].document is undefined.

So how can I make changes to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use `items[i].document.getElementsByTagName("li")`? Use, if you must, `items[i].getElementsByTagName("li")`. Or, just use `document.querySelectorAll('ol li').forEach((li) => li.style.backgroundColor = "red")`...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `items[i].document.getElementsByTagName("li")` with `items[i].getElementsByTagName("li")`

you cannot access the `document` from `items[i]` so all what you have to do is to remove `document` and directly use `items[i].getElementsByTagName("li")`